# Node.js consecutive method calls with nested callback formatting

Tags: node.js

So I'm new to Node.js and Im just wondering if the way I have my code setup makes sense. Im coming from a Java background so the nested callback structure is new. I have a Node program that runs a bunch of code that I broke down into different methods. The thing is that the methods need to be called in order. My code has this structure right now:

```
functionOne(data, callback(err) {

   functionTwo(data, callback(err) {

      functionThree(data, callback(err) {

          functionFour(data, callback(err) {
             //Code
          });

      });

   });

});
```

This is very minimalistic, but is this structure ok? With Java, I'd take the return values of all the methods, then just pass them to the next function. From my understanding so far, the Java approach I just mentioned is one of the main things that Node.js was trying to eliminate. But anyway... Does that structure look ok, and is that how its intended to look? Just want to be sure that I'm not making any major errors with Node in general. Thanks!

Comment: I believe Promises is what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to use `promises` to avoid your callback hell, so it could be something like these...

```
const Q = require('q'); // you can do a research for this module.
var myModule = {};
myModule.functionOne = (params) => {
  const deferred = Q.defer(); // wait for this to complete
  // body function
  deferred.resolve(data); // this would be the result of this function
  return deferred.promise; // data is the output on your function
}

myModule.functionTwo = (params) => {
  const deferred = Q.defer(); // wait for this to complete
  // body function
  deferred.resolve(data); // this would be the result of this function
  return deferred.promise; // data is the output on your function
}

myModule.doAll = (params) => {
   myModule.functionOne(params)
   .then((outputFunctionOne) => {
      // this is called after functionOne ends
      return myModule.functionTwo(outputFunctionOne);
   })
   .then((outputFunctionTwo) => {
      // this is called after function 2 ends
      if (outputFunctionTwo.success) {
        // if everything ok, resolve the promise with the final output
        deferred.resolve(outputFunctionTwo);
      } else {
        // reject the promise with an error message
        deferred.reject('error');
      }
   })
   .fail((err) => { 
      // this is call if the promise is rejected or an exception is thrown
      console.log(err); // TODO: Error handling
   })
   .done();
}

module.exports = myModule;
```

You can Chain as many promises as you want really easily, that way you get rid of the callback hell. Best part, you can do promises on Javascript or Node.js

Reference Link https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Hope this helps

Comment: Is the callback system a common criticism of Node? I know that all tutorials that I've seen have said ".. and the great thing is that you can pass the callback function right in the method call! Hooray!", but it seems like doing this over and over like Im doing will create code that's hard to follow

Comment: Yes basically if you chain your promises, you can have your data dependencies (or function dependencies) aligned to a single level, instead of the need or reading code dependencies of a lot of nested functions. Code is cleaner ande more readable. I don't think the callback hell is just in node, it could happen also in Javascript. Promises is a very nice way to solve it :)

Comment: Where does 'outputFunctionOne' come from? Is that automatically passed to the next _then()_ call with the return statement of the previous method?

Comment: I've edited my answer... basically what you put in `deferred.resolve(data)` is what you catch on the `.then` functions...

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much! Ill have to try and work this into my code!

Comment: Here's another good and easy example :) http://12devs.co.uk/articles/promises-an-alternative-way-to-approach-asynchronous-javascript/

Comment: @rpm The callback system is overall a GOOD thing. From a functional programming perspective, it allows you to build up async calls using standard libraries and preserve a sane control flow structure. The disadvantage is that you end up with sever nesting. The Promise/A spec was designed to alleviate this, whilst preserving the ability to chain standard library functions together. It has become the defacto standard in javascript for all async work (given js lacks synchronous blocking calls, that means everything).

Comment: Saying callbacks are a common criticism of Node is like saying that the setjmp/longjmp is a common criticism of the C language. In day to day usage, you shouldn't need to go that far down in the code.

Answer (score 5):

Your code structure looks fine if you work with callback pattern.
But if you're interested in make your code cleaner and readable you would like to use Promises in your asynchronous function, so instead of pass a callback to your functions you could do something like this :

```
function asyncFunction (data){
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
       // Do something with data
       // Here you can call reject(error) to throw an error
       resolve();
   });
}
```

And instead of nested function callbacks you can call then method of Promise.

```
asyncFunction(data)
.then(function(){
    // Promise resolved
    // Something has been done with data
});
```

With Promises you can also execute async fuctions in parallel :

```
Promise.all([asyncFunctionA(data), asyncFunctionB(data), asyncFunctionC(data)])
.then(function(){...});
```

**EDIT**

If you need to pass values of one function to another, your code should look like this :

```
asyncFunctionA(data)
.then(function(dataA){
    return asyncFunctionB(dataA);
})
.then(function(dataB){
    return asyncFunctionC(dataB);
})
.then(function(dataC){
// ...
});
```

Comment: So I'd be able to string together "then()" calls so pass data from one method to another?

Comment: In general however, modern libraries will return promise/A objects when called without a callback. So you are unlikely to need to write these wrappers.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the other answers give Promise/A as the answer to your callback woes. This is correct, and will work for you. However I'd like to give you another option, if you are willing to drop javascript as your working language.

Introducing **Iced Coffee**, a branch of the CoffeeScript project.

With Iced Coffee you would write:

```
await functionOne data, defer err
await functionTwo data, defer err2
await functionThree data, defer err3
//etc
```

This then compiles to the CoffeeScript:

```
functionOne data, (err) ->
   functionTwo data, (err2) ->
      functionThree data, (err3) ->
         //etc
```

Which then compiles to your Javascript.

```
functionOne(data, callback(err) {

   functionTwo(data, callback(err2) {

      functionThree(data, callback(err3) {
          //etc    
      });    
   });    
});
```